# Monitor the network shared folder?

Tags: windows, network-shares, monitoring

I am looking for freeware/open source application which can monitor the shared folder on local network. I did use some freeware application , but forgot its name.

I Would like to see who are all currently using that particular folder and even get notified when changes happen.

Comment: What do you want exactly? See which folder are shared on the network? Or be warned when the content of a shared folder changes?

Comment: What operating system are you talking about?

Comment: Added Tag, I am taking about Windows XP or Higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for a tool to alert you when someone is accessing your shared folders, see this article:
[Monitor and Notify when Shared Folders being Accessed](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2007/03/11/monitor-and-notify-when-shared-folders-being-accessed/)

Or this article for a tool that can tell what file the user is actually accessing and can log it down for future reference:
[Track Who Modified or Deleted Files in Your Shared Folder](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/05/22/track-who-modified-or-deleted-files-in-your-shared-folder/)

Answer (score 0):

Read the Globinch.com article on good tools to [Monitor Shared Folders and Network Folders in Windows and Get Notified](https://web.archive.org/web/20111209095757/http://www.globinch.com/2011/03/03/monitor-shared-folders-monitor-network-folders-in-windows/)

Quote from the article:

> Using “Computer Management” you can easily find out who is accessing your Shared Folder.
>
> How do you access “Computer Management”?.
>
> - Go to Control Panel -> Performance and Maintenance -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management
> - Or Right Click My Computer – > Manage -> Computer Management
>
> Expand the “Shared Folders“. Here you can see shares, sessions and open files.

The article also suggested the following tools:

- ShareWatcher by [CodeLine](http://www.thecodeline.com/wp/products/sharewatcher)
- ShareMonitor by [Abdollah Zawari](https://csharptips.wordpress.com/2010/03/02/monitoring-access-to-your-shared-files-on-network/) official [download from Softpedia](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Network-Tools/Network-Monitoring/ShareMonitor.shtml)
- NetShareMonitor by [SecurityXploded](http://www.securityxploded.com/netsharemonitor.php)

Comment: Can you copy and paste information from links, instead of JUST the link? It prevents links going dead and answers not having direction later on in the future

Comment: Be wary of NetShareMonitor: [Virustotal scan of the last version (at the moment of writing)](https://www.virustotal.com/es/file/a2508e9158aa2f4f627b49ee3658ff3f25125682a82968713ad594efffa347fa/analysis/1436492148/).